# How can I slide this React drawer from left to right

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms, drawer

I made a drawer in React, that I got from the internet

The problem is that it always slides from right to left, and I don't know to to make it slide from left to right

The CSS code for the drawer is:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.side-drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 40%;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.side-drawer.open {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

I don't know why it slides the way it does, I guess it is related to transition/transform

How can I make it slide from left to right?

I made a sandbox for it

[image: Edit React Side Drawer]

Thanks in advance

Rafael

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

this is my new CSS:

```
.side-drawer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%; /* changed it */
  width: 40%;
  z-index: 200;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(0); /* changed it */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
.side-drawer.open {
  transform: translateX(100%); /* changed it */
}
```